# paganation using ajax can work but next page shows all the left page rather than just one page a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, pagination

I have made a laravel site that use laravel's pagination and jquery ajax to load the next page when scrolling to the bottom.
It did succeed, but the next page is just loading all the left content rather than one page at a time.Besides when i scroll down , it keep loading , it just do not stop. I do not know what's  wrong with it.

//post home that needs loaded automatically

```
  <section class="mainContent">
      @foreach($posts as $post)
         <article class="articleList">
              {{$post->user->username}}
               ....
         <article>
      @endforeach
   </section>

   <section class="postHomeBottom">
       {{$posts->links()}}    
    </section>
```

//ajaxPost  ajax/products page

```
  @foreach($posts as $post)
     <article class="articleList">
          {{$post->user->username}}
           ....
     <article>
  @endforeach

 {{$posts->links()}}
```

//jquery ajax code

```
var page = 1;

function getProducts(page){
    console.log('getting products for page = ' + page);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/html5lav/public/ajax/products?page=' + page
    })
    .done(function(data){
      if(data != ''){
            console.log(data);
            $('.articleList').append(data);
             location.hash = page;

              flag = true;

            $('.pagination').hide();          
      }else{
            $('<div class="well">No more feeds</div>').insertBefore('.pagination');
            $('.pagination').remove();       
      }  

    })


}

$(document).on('click','.pagination li:last-child a', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log($(this).attr('href').split('page='));
    //var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
    getProducts(page);


});



var flag = true;

$(window).scroll(function(){


 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){

          page =page + 1;

           var active = $('.pagination li:last-child').hasClass('active');

           if(flag && !active){
              flag = false;
              $('.pagination li:last-child a').trigger('click');
           }
           //return;


    }
});
```

Comment: while you use .append the code will append data each time you click on li:last a .. so you can use .html() instead of .append() .. or make a condition like put the each loaded page in div and just show the div you need

Comment: @ Mohamed,  i need it to append it to the bottom like twitter did, if use html then the original conent will be gone

Comment: you need to check that you are limiting your query correctly , since you didnt put your php code we cant tell you where the issue is